# Teammate cannot edit bigquery scheduled query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I created a scheduled query in bigquery and I want my teammate to be able to edit it. However when they attempt to update and save the query there is a error message that only says "Scheduled Query Error". They can edit their own scheduled queries but cannot edit ones that I created.

I can confirm that they have all of the permissions in the link below.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#required_permissions

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score -1):

A solution could be to create a service account and assign the correct permissions. Then you need to grant access to the users who will access this scheduled query.

You can follow these steps:

- Create a [service account](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) in the IAM menu.You can see this
  [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-role).

[image]

- [Grant access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-role) to the users (users who access the scheduled query)
  to the service account you will use.